# How add object to list in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, pojo

How I can add object to list via REST methods without adding key to object in Firebase?

Now I have this structure:

```
{
  "-KAG0XPYF_n8DRT55lwV": {
    "GCMTocken": "rtdjhsrfjt546456",
    "firstName": "Pasha",
    "gender": 1,
    "lastName": "Strongman",
    "likes": 0,
    "nickname": "drake1804",
    "uid": "facebook:957484857633657"
  },
  "-QPG0XPYF_n8DRT5VM": {
    "GCMTocken": "rfgjfrty1232",
    "firstName": "Josh",
    "gender": 1,
    "lastName": "Wayne",
    "likes": 0,
    "nickname": "nick",
    "uid": "facebook:957484492264"
  }
}
```

I need like this:

```
{
    {
        "GCMTocken": "rtdjhsrfjt546456",
        "firstName": "Pasha",
        "gender": 1,
        "lastName": "Strongman",
        "likes": 0,
        "nickname": "drake1804",
        "uid": "facebook:957484857633657"
    }
}
```

Comment: The Firebase Database stores JSON. That last snippet is not valid JSON, so you cannot create it in Firebase.

Comment: The big question here is *why* do you need it like that? Why do you need to  have a data without a key?

Comment: because firebase return an array of data, typical data which i should handle via retrofit @Jay

Comment: Everything is Firebase is Key:Value pairs so there is never a situation where only an array is returned; there's always a key involved.  snapshot.key for example and your array would be in snapshot.value. If you can clarify what you are after we may be able to assist.